# Converting an AF_INET socket to use AF_UNIX via LD_PRELOAD

Tags: c, sockets, ld-preload

I'm wondering how feasible it is to be able to convert an AF_INET socket to use an  AF_UNIX instead.  The reason for this is that I've got a program which will open a TCP socket, but which we cannot change.  To reduce overhead we would therefore like to instead tie this socket to use an AF_UNIX one for its communication instead.

So far, my idea has been to use LD_PRELOAD to achieve this---intercepting bind() and accept(), however it is not clear how best to achieve this, or even if this is the best approach.

So far, bind in bind(), if the socket type is AF_INET and its IP/port is the socket I wish to convert to AF_UNIX, I then close the sockd here, and open an AF_UNIX one.  However, this seems to be causing problems further on in accept() -- because I am unsure what to do when the sockfd in accept() matches the one I wish to tell to use an AF_UNIX socket.

Any help kindly appreciated.

Jason

Comment: Despite the fact that I wrote an answer, I found this question to be a bad fit for the site's format. I almost voted to close it as "not constructive". The problem is that the answer to "is this feasible?" is more or less just "yes". In the future, I would suggest asking a more direct question, such as a question about a specific aspect of implementing this wrapper that you are having trouble with.

Comment: Thanks, Celada.  I've amended the question now to be a little clearer.

Comment: The [socket_wrapper](https://cwrap.org/socket_wrapper.html) library provides this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea sounds perfectly feasible. In fact, I think it sounds like the best way to achieve what you want. I wouldn't expect very different, or even measurably different, overhead/performance though.

Of course you'd also have to intercept `socket()` in addition to `bind()` and `accept()`. In `bind()`, you could, for example, converted the requested TCP port to a fixed pathname `/tmp/converted_socket.<port-number>` or something like that.

Comment: So... in socket() I would keep a track of which FDs have been created.In bind() if a sockfd I've found matches this, and the IP/port of this socket is the one I want to convert, I then open an AF_UNIX socket with a correct path, and bind that, and then convert the sockaddr* passed in to bind()?  What happens then in accept()?

Comment: Oh, I see now that you want to delay the decision of whether you rewrite the system call to `bind()`. Then you don't need to intercept `socket()` I guess. You can bait-and-switch the socket inside `bind()`. Anyway, in `accept()` you will need to convert the sockaddr argument back from `sockaddr_un` to `sockaddr_in` or `sockaddr_in6`.

Comment: Yes, Celada---I would need to delay this since for most other requests to bind() they just pass through unmodified by me, hence the wrangling in the specific case.  Would you happen to have a good example of how to achieve this?  I admit to struggling a little with the conversion.

Comment: You mean converting the sockaddr from `in` to `un` and back? You just have to use an ad-hoc mapping such as I propose in my answer... or if you know you are only ever dealing with one listening socket, just use a fixed string for the `sockaddr_un` address and return a dummy fixed `sockaddr_in` address from `accept()`.

Comment: Ok... just so I have the mechanics of this correct...  In bind(), I identify the sockfd of the socket I wish to convert, and at the same time, open up an AF_UNIX and bind to it.  Then in accept(), if the sockfd I've accept()ed is the one which should be the AF_UNIX one, I assign its 'struct sockaddr *' a sockaddr_in one from the AF_UNIX socket I opened in bind()?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and came up with [unsock](https://github.com/kohlschutter/unsock), a shim library that does what you describe, and more.

*unsock* supports other address types like `AF_VSOCK` and `AF_TIPC`, and the Firecracker VM multiplexing proxy as well.

There are three key insights I want to share:

1. Since sockets are created for a particular address family using `socket(2)`, and then later connected or bound using `connect(2)`/`bind(2)`,  you may be tempted to simply intercept `socket` and fix the address there.

   One problem is that you may want to selectively intercept certain addresses only, which you don't know at the time of the call.

   The other problem is that file descriptors may be passed upon you from another process (e.g., via `AF_UNIX` auxiliary mes, so you may not be able to intercept `socket(2)` in the first place.

   In other words, you need to intercept `connect(2)`, `bind(2)`, and `sendto(2)`.
2. When you intercept `connect(2)`, `bind(2)`, and `sendto(2)`, you need to retroactively change the address family for `socket(2)`. Thankfully, you can just create a new socket and use `dup3(2)` to reassign the new socket to the existing file descriptor. This saves a lot of housekeeping!
3. `accept(2)` and `recvfrom(2)` also need to be intercepted, and the returned addresses converted back to something the caller understands. This will inevitably break certain assumptions unless you do maintain a mapping back to the actual, non-`AF_INET` address.