# LD_PRELOAD socket calls cause Segmentation fault at bind() syscall

Tags: segmentation-fault, bind, ld-preload

I'm trying to LD_PRELOAD (`LD_PRELOAD=./my_lib.so ./a.out`) an executable with simple `AF_INET` socket calls. 
I want to catch the call, and proceed with `AF_VSOCK` address family instead of `AF_INET`.
`socket()`, `connect()` works well. The problem is when I call `bind()` I get a segmentation fault
(`segfault at 60 ip 00007f4f4b2ea59a sp 00007fff9eb53dd8 error 4 in libc-2.13.so[7f4f4b261000+184000]`)

lib.so:

```
typedef int (*bind_orig_ftype)(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr,socklen_t addrlen);

int bind(int sockfd, const struct sockaddr *addr, socklen_t addrlen)
{
    bind_orig_ftype bind_original;
    struct sockaddr_vm vmaddr;

    bind_original= (bind_orig_ftype) dlsym(RTLD_NEXT,"bind");

    vmaddr.svm_family = AF_VSOCK;
    vmaddr.svm_cid = 42;
    vmaddr.svm_port = 1234;
    printf("Intercepted\n");
    return (bind_original(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *) &vmaddr,sizeof(struct sockaddr)));
}
```

I got "Intercepted" printed and then the `segfault`. I'm thinking the problem is about `struct sockaddr_vm` passing it to bind_original, but when I call bind at `AF_VSOCK`, without LD_PRELOADing everything works well.

Any ideas? Or how to check where the sefault occurs?

Comment: Use `sizeof vmaddr`. If your code is the server, then use `VMADDR_CID_ANY` and `VMADDR_PORT_ANY` when initialising the structure. Then use a debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the address type also requires changing the socket domain, among other things.

See my answer to [Converting an AF_INET socket to use AF_UNIX via LD_PRELOAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74293935/515310) for some key takeaways.

If you need a fully-working library that supports `AF_VSOCK`, for both *vhost-vsock* as well as *Firecracker*-style multiplexing Unix domain sockets, have a look at [unsock](https://github.com/kohlschutter/unsock).